# Couldn't Access Array inside If statement which is present in the for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function identifybrand ( allproducts,favBrand){ 
  var favBrandList = new Array();
  var prodType = document.getElementById('prodType').value;
  for (var i=0;i<=allproducts.length;i++) {
    if (favBrand == allproducts[i].brandName) {
      favBrandList.push(allproducts[i]);
    }
  }
  alert(favBrandList);
}
```

I couldnt access the favBrandList array outside the for loop. Does anyone have any idea why i m not able to access it?

Comment: Are you getting any values in `allproducts`? Have you tried alerting the values?

Comment: Where do you use prodType?

Comment: yeah....if i put alert inside for loop i can see the array. but its couldn't access it outside.

Comment: I m not using it...jus kept it thr wrongly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason should be you are getting a script error in the loop.

Your loop is faulty, `i<=allproducts.length` is wrong it should be `i<allproducts.length`.

Array index starts `from 0 to length - 1`, so when `i` equals `allproducts.length`, `allproducts[i]` becomes undefined and `allproducts[i].brandName` will throw a script error.

```
function identifybrand(allproducts, favBrand) {
    var favBrandList = new Array();
    var prodType = document.getElementById('prodType').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < allproducts.length; i++) {
        if (favBrand == allproducts[i].brandName) {
            favBrandList.push(allproducts[i]);
        }
    }
    alert(favBrandList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still i m not able to access it.

Comment: what do you mean by not able to access?

Comment: i mean if i put the alert inside the for loop, i can actually see the array forming. But if i try put alert for favBrandList array out side the for loop, i m not getting any alert.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Right from the beginning i was putting i<=. :-)